# CQWP ItemStyle: how to display background of description with conditional formatting

Tags: content-query-web-part, xslt, formatting

I have 3 elements in a field and I would like the CQWP to display red as a bg colour of the field or amber or green.

I guess the starting point is

```
<xsl:if test="RAG = 'Red'">background-color: #FFFF00;</xsl:if>
```

or something similar, please correct,

but I am not sure where to place it.

Consider I am using the standard one

```
        <div class="description">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Description" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not wish to add style sheet as explain by @JJD then just update your item style sheet as below :

```
<div class="description">   
<xsl:attribute name="style">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="(@RAG = 'red')">background-color: red;</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="(@RAG = 'amber')">background-color: amber;</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="(@RAG = 'green')">background-color: green;</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:value-of select="@Description" /> 
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: this code broke the whole thing. I have replaced the 2 original lines of description with this and the webpart gives an error message

Comment: my rag is non-capital and my colours are written with capital letter (Red, Amber etc) , I have adapted yours to my situation but it is still not working

Comment: RAG - is column name where if value is 'red' it will apply background as red to your description div. This is tested works in my SPO environment.

Comment: I hope you are updating fields to display section of web part properties.

Comment: ok, there was one div too much, the colour amber does not display. Can I replace it with hex numbers?

Comment: Yes you can replace with hex code . Any inline style you want to apply you can do it this way.

Comment: is there a reason why the colours display in chrome and not in IE or firefox?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82651/discussion-between-bhaskar-dhone-and-susan).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an xsl file? In that case it would be something like

```
<div>   
<xsl:attribute name="class">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="(@RAG = 'red')">Descriptionred</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="(@RAG = 'amber')">Descriptionamber</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="(@RAG = 'green')">Descriptiongreen</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:value-of select="@Description" /> 
</div>
```

assuming 'red', 'green' and 'amber' are values from a 'RAG' column

basic styling

```
    <style>
    .Descriptionred{background:red;}
    .Descriptionamber {background:orange;}
    .Descriptiongreen{background:green;}    
    </style>
```

*Descriptionred* ,*Descriptionamber* and *Descriptiongreen* are classes which gets applied to **div** which renders description. Stylesheet for these columns needs to added on the page where you will add content query webpart.

Comment: i am using the original itemstyle.xsl in SharePoint. It is something very close to what is displayed in this page http://tdemeul.bunnybesties.org/2018/04/sharepoint-custom-cqwp-using-xsl.html

Comment: Are you able to put your script one and 2 in the same template?